# Read and write to Modbus RTU

Tags: python-3.x, iot, modbus

I'm using minimalmodbus for reading and writing. I have USB to Rs485 connection.

I'm trying to write this "02 05 0000 ff11" to RTU register in python but i'm getting error. Here is my code.

**Device address:** 02

**Function code:** 05

**Register Address:** 0000

**Value:** ff00

```
 import minimalmodbus
 instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM4', 1)
 instrument.write_register(02, 05, 0000, ff00)
```

**I need the same functionality in the above code using python!**

[image: I need this functionality in Python script]

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up some settings.

The Modbus slave address (2 in your case) should be included in the instantiation of the instrument:

```
instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM4', 2)
```

And the arguments you are using for the `write_register` function are wrong as well, they should be:

```
instrument.write_register(0, 0xff00)
```

As you can see `write_register` only takes two arguments: the register number and the value you want to read in it.

It might be a good idea to take a look at [the code](https://github.com/pyhys/minimalmodbus/blob/master/minimalmodbus.py) and/or [some examples](https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html).

**EDIT**: I realized you actually want to use function code 05 (write coils). To do that you should use `write_bit` function instead:

```
instrument.write_bit(0, 1)
```

That means write `True` on coil 0.

Comment: Hey Marcos, thanks for your help. I have tried it but still no communication.

`File "C:\Users\Waqas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py", line 1406, in _communicate
    raise NoResponseError("No communication with the instrument (no answer)")
minimalmodbus.NoResponseError: No communication with the instrument (no answer)`

Comment: That means you have no connection with your device. Is it working with conmix? Have you tried reading registers instead of writing?

Comment: By the way, function code is for writing coils, not registers. You should probably be using `write_bit` instead of `write_register`. See update on my answer.

Comment: I applied your changes to my code!

`File "C:\Users\Waqas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 315, in write
    raise SerialException("WriteFile failed ({!r})".format(ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: WriteFile failed (PermissionError(13, 'The device does not recognize the command.', None, 22)) `

Comment: That error seems to mean your port is open by another process, have you closed conmix or any other tools using the port? Otherwise reboot and try again...